# Saxon s9api merge node elements to exiting node

Tags: saxon, s9api

When trying to merge elements from a node retrieved from integrated extension function ( as an argument) into an existing node, NPE appears.

We're trying to compare and merge childnodes from an "old" node int to a "new" node (does childnode exist, then overwrite with new value retrieved from argument or childnode doesn't exist so create childnode in "new" node).

```
public XdmValue call(XdmValue[] arguments) throws SaxonApiException {
            String sessionId = arguments[0].itemAt(0).getStringValue();
            XdmNode tempNode = TransformationService.tempNodes.get(sessionId);
            // new Child Nodes from provided TempNode
            List<SaplingElement> newChildNodes = new ArrayList<>(arguments[1]
                    .select(Steps.child().then(Steps.child()))
                    .map(childNode -> Saplings.elem(childNode.getNodeName()).withText(childNode.itemAt(0).getStringValue())).toList());
            // old Child Nodes of old TempNode (if exists) filtered by elements of provided TempNode and won't be updated
            List<SaplingElement> oldChildNodes = (tempNode != null)
                    ? new ArrayList<>(tempNode.select(Steps.child().then(Steps.child()))
                    .map(childNode -> Saplings.elem(childNode.getNodeName()).withText(childNode.itemAt(0).getStringValue()))
                    .filter(saplingElement -> !newChildNodes.contains(saplingElement)).toList())
                    : Collections.emptyList();

            // merge new with old child notes
            newChildNodes.addAll(oldChildNodes);

            Processor processor = ((XdmNode) arguments[1]).getProcessor();
            tempNode = Saplings.elem("TempNode").withChild(newChildNodes.toArray(new SaplingElement[]{})).toXdmNode(processor);

            TransformationService.tempNodes.put(sessionId, tempNode);
            return tempNode;
        }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208) ~[na:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.sapling.SaplingElement.<init>(SaplingElement.java:90) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.sapling.Saplings.elem(Saplings.java:62) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at de.dkl.dymoServer.util.ExternalFunctions$1.lambda$call$1(ExternalFunctions.java:46) ~[main/:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.streams.XdmStream.forEach(XdmStream.java:360) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[na:na]

    at de.dkl.dymoServer.util.ExternalFunctions$1.call(ExternalFunctions.java:47) ~[main/:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor$ExtensionFunctionDefinitionWrapper$1.call(Processor.java:732) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.functions.IntegratedFunctionCall.iterate(IntegratedFunctionCall.java:297) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.elab.FallbackElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPull$0(FallbackElaborator.java:46) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.AtomicSequenceConverter$AtomicSequenceConverterElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPull$0(AtomicSequenceConverter.java:517) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.elab.PullElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$0(PullElaborator.java:38) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf$ValueOfElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$1(ValueOf.java:423) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.MessageInstr$MessageInstrElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$0(MessageInstr.java:338) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:396) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.handleRuleNotNull(Mode.java:568) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:502) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.trans.XsltController.applyTemplates(XsltController.java:684) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.AbstractXsltTransformer.applyTemplatesToSource(AbstractXsltTransformer.java:427) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:359) ~[Saxon-HE-12.0.jar:na]

    at de.dkl.dymoServer.service.TransformationService.transform(TransformationService.java:135) ~[main/:na]

    at de.dkl.dymoServer.service.TransformationService.performTransformations(TransformationService.java:90) ~[main/:na]

    at de.dkl.dymoServer.web.controller.TransformationController.getTransformationResult(TransformationController.java:45) ~[main/:na]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:73) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Don't know why NPE appears when trying to add with toList()

Comment: Which of the posted lines is `ExternalFunctions.java:46` giving the exception? And why do you use XSLT but try to transform nodes with a Java API, why can't anything of that be done in XSLT itself?

Comment: I don't think the attempt `.filter(saplingElement -> !newChildNodes.contains(saplingElement))` to identify equal or similar elements makes any sense, it falls back to `java.lang.Object.equals` which only gives true for identical objects based on object id.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE occurs because you are supplying a null value to the method `Saplings.elem()`. Your call is `Saplings.elem(childNode.getNodeName())`, so one can assume that `childNode` is a node that has no name -- probably a text node, perhaps a whitespace text node.

Since you are processing all the children of some node, it seems likely that these children include text nodes as well as element nodes.

If you only want to process element nodes, change

```
.select(Steps.child().then(Steps.child()))
```

to

```
.select(Steps.child("*").then(Steps.child("*")))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to modify (add, replace, delete) an xdmNode children?